# Is there any Terminal command to find the files installed by a particular App?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, command-line, file

Is there any terminal command which allows the user to input the name of the application along with the command, executing which shows you all the hidden files and folders the app has created or installed on your mac

Comment: I don't know about that, but if you are looking for a cleaner way to uninstall apps, I'd recommend [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). It finds those files that are not removed, when you trash an application.

Comment: @Joonas It doesn't

Comment: [That's exactly what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja0OW.png)... but I didn't say it is perfect. It does sometimes miss some files.

Comment: @Joonas I guess there is a grep command for searching files but I don't have much information about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files created by apps are usually in `/Library` and subfolders likes `Application Support`, `Caches`...

The files are not created by a specific user "AppName" but with your user account rights (or root one for some of them). So there is no way to locate App created files, unless if the app correctly named them.

So you can use the find command like that:

```
$ find /Libray -name "*AppName*"
```

http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-using-the-find-command-1305633

Grep command can work too:

```
$ ls -la /Library | grep "AppName"
```

Comment: The find finds more than a grep eg if the authors put all their apps under the company name then th app name

Comment: Also these find global files not the one in your home directory